# Why code works with SaveChanges but not with SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 with VS2015. I would like to understand the following in a portion of my controller code: The last line of the following code gives the error: `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`. But if I change `SaveChangesAsync()` to `SaveChanges()` code works fine.

**Snapshot of Controller**:

```
public IActionResult myActionMethod(...)
{
    ...
    var oRecToUpdate = _context.Order.Where(c => c.OrdersId == 104).SingleOrDefault();
    if (oRecToUpdate != null)
    {
        oRecToUpdate.Price = 98.09;
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    string sStateNumer = _context.StateNames
        .Where(s => s.State == "myState").Select(t => t.StateNumber).SingleOrDefault();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Your not `await`ing the `async` call. You should be

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `await` on that call to`SaveChangesAsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling an asynchronous method on the context, it's potentially still running by the time you get to the next query. You need to `await` the call to prevent this:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Or call the non-asynchronous version:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I should have pointed out that the signature of my action method is not using `async` keyword. It's simply `Public IActionResult myActionMethod(...){...}`. But VS2015 does not complain about using `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` without `await`. I've just added that to my code above

Comment: Why would it complain? It's syntactically correct, but semantically wrong. Resharper would tell you there's an issue though.